# Использование типа в DLL библиотеке и в приложении

Tags: c++, dll

Пишу DLL библиотеку на C++. В ней есть некоторая функция. Она принимает на вход type&, где type - некоторый тип (класс), определенный в библиотеке и не специфицированный для экспорта. Если я в проекте, использующем данную библиотеку определю идентично этот класс и вызову функцию из dll с аргументом - экземпляром определенного в проекте класса, то будет ли это работать адекватно?

Возможно, есть варианты, как сделать это по-другому?

Или можно сделать .hpp файл с этим классом и включить его и в проект и в библиотеку?

Comment: нет. Вас ожидают захватывающие приключения с отлаживанием кода, передающего классы через границы исполняемых модулей. Не говоря о распределении/очищении памяти в разных местах.

Comment: @Igor А какой вариант тогда, если я хочу вынести функции, работающие с классами проекта в dll? И в чем будет проблема с общим хедером?

Comment: Я, конечно, слишком сильно выразился. При некоторых оганичениях - например, явное задание выравнивания членов, распределение/очищение памяти по одну сторону от границы exe модулей, такое возможно. Но Вы должны постоянно об этом помнить. А вот Windows API - пример другого подхода, обмен данными происходит через простые типы и структуры.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в DLL использовать пользовательский тип?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630035/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-dll-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Если я в проекте, использующем данную библиотеку определю идентично этот класс и вызову функцию из dll с аргументом - экземпляром определенного в проекте класса, то будет ли это работать адекватно?

Да, так это делается. Надо лишь следить не только за полной идентичностью определения класса, но и за идентичностью таких настроек компилятора, как выравнивание.

> Или можно сделать .hpp файл с этим классом и включить его и в проект и в библиотеку?

Разумеется, именно таким способом и добиваются идентичности определения класса: помещают определение класса в заголовочный файл и включают его везде, где оно нужно.

Вся технология практически ничем не отличается от банального использования одного класса в нескольких единицах трансляции. С той только разницей, что на некоторых платформах надо предпринимать дополнительные усилия по экспорту/импорту внешних символов.

Comment: Я не очень понял насчет выравнивания, буду благодарен за доп информацию. И что мне делать на MSVS? Если я включу этот хедер с классом и в dll и в проект, все нормально будет? Просто этот хедер можно сделать стат либой, из него не получится применять __declspec(dllexport). Или тут еще какие-то механизмы есть?